How can I know how much the scammer (creator of scam token) has made off us?
I fell for honeypot a few months ago when I was just starting to explore the world of cryptocurrency. I was scammed out of $50 along with many other guys who bought and then couldn't sell the token. I attach a link to the token contract. I understand he withdrew all the liquidity to himself, but I do not understand how and where to see it and what the total amount of scam (it is very interesting to me)
Scam token:
https://www.geckoterminal.com/ru/bsc/pools/0x679d0940d1f524ce1c69b0cc18a81b4893da8609
